# How to query Microstrategy metadata?

Tags: microstrategy

I've been working in the past few years with Cognos 10 and Cognos 11 but my company has Microstrategy (I'm a newbie in Microstrategy). So I want to create an embedded query to know which last objects were modified by an user and that sort of things. I know which tables to query because I googled it and I found [this blog entry](http://bipostit.com/en/2014/12/28/queries-metadata-i/), but I don't know the schema of this tables.

Can someone help me to acomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the modification date (create_time, mod_time) in the object table.

```
SELECT
    project_id,
    object_id,
    object_type,
    subtype,
    object_name,
    abbreviation,
    description,
    version_id,
    parent_id,
    owner_id,
    hidden,
    **create_time,
    mod_time,**
    object_uname,
    object_state,
    locale,
    extended_type,
    view_media,
    icon_path
FROM
    meta.dssmdobjinfo;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on about MetaData queries:

```
SELECT DISTINCT B.OBJECT_NAME AS NOMBRE,
                A.USER_ID,
                C.OBJECT_NAME AS CAMBIADO_POR,
                D.CREATE_TIME AS F_CREACION,
                D.MOD_TIME AS F_MODIFICACION
  FROM DSSMDJRNINFO A
       JOIN DSSMDJRNOBJD B
          ON A.TRANSACTION_ID = B.TRANSACTION_ID
       JOIN DSSMDOBJINFO C
          ON A.USER_ID = C.OBJECT_ID
       JOIN DSSMDOBJINFO D
          ON     B.OBJECT_NAME = D.OBJECT_NAME
             AND (SYSDATE - 7) <= (D.MOD_TIME - 0);
```

Source: http://khaidoan.wikidot.com/mstr-metadata-queries